# Difference between jbyteArray and jbyte pointer

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I'm new to JNI. I'm confused with jbyteArray and jbyte pointer. Can anyone tell me what is the difference between jbyteArray and jbyte pointer? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, if a tool like [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) meets your needs, it could save you a lot of trouble :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `jbyteArray` is a handle to a Java object of type `byte[]`. A `jbyte` pointer, or in other words, `jbyte*`, is a native C data type, that can take the address of a native `signed char[]` array, for example, but it does not map to any Java data type.

An object referenced by a `jbyteArray` is a Java object, so like any other Java object, we cannot deallocate it manually. It probably will eventually get deallocated by the garbage collector though, once it becomes out of reach. In JNI, for example, global references can be allocated and deallocated with `NewGlobalRef()` and `DeleteGlobalRef()`, so make sure to call the latter if you call the former, that's it.

Comment: Thanks. But I have another question. If I'm using jbyteArray, how can I release the jbyteArray. I found ReleaseByteArrayElements, but it only release the jbyte pointer not the jByteArray according to the doc from [here]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp23720(). Do you know how to actually release the jbyteArray?

Comment: @tonylin Ok, I've updated my answer, now please update your question! Thanks